# Is chars[4] and 4[chars] the same in C? Why?

Tags: c

I've read this and don't believe it :) I've no compiler here to test.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In raw C, the `[]` notation is just a pointer math helper.  Before `[]`, you'd look for the fourth char in the block pointed to by `ptr` like:

```
*(ptr+4)
```

Then, they introduced a shortcut which looked better:

```
ptr[4]
```

Which transaltes to the earlier expression.  But, if you'd write it like:

```
4[ptr]
```

This would translate to:

```
*(4+ptr)
```

Which is indeed the same thing.

Comment: so chars is a pointer to the begining of the my char[] array. Right?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what a C array is.  It's a pointer to the first element of the array

Comment: Technically not quite - see: http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/c-faq/c-2.html (but for the purposes of this answer, they're close enough!)

Answer (score 5):

Because a[b] is exactly the same as *(a+b), and + is commutatitve.

`chars[4]` is `*(chars+4)`, and `4[chars]` is `*(4+chars)`

Comment: What's char+4? and what's *(chars+4)?

Comment: char + 4 is a pointer to the fourth character in the array and *(chars+4) dereferences this pointer to give the character at the chars[4] location

Answer (score 4):

http://c-faq.com/aryptr/joke.html
Try this to test compile: http://codepad.org/